# How to create a package in Cognos - SDK?

Tags: java, sdk, cognos

I have been trying to create a package for Cognos via the sdk.

So far so good. I can created a package but I cannot add a datasource to that package. So basicly it does not do anything.

I am getting:

> ANS-MES-0003 A server error occurred. Unable to complete the action.

when launching the package with the analysis studio.

Comment: I have tried to create the package with a model, package-configuration, model and modelview.
@Nielsvh do you have working java or c# code? Maybe you can post it here so I can have a look at it and maybe draw conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS, you may not be getting the underlying issue because IIS will intercept the error. The error may be bad permissions or corrupt user data, but the error code returned seems to be an umbrella for specifics.

As outlined [in this troubleshooting page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21470999), you can see the original error by setting httpErrors to PassThough. Replace:

```
<httpErrors lockAttributes="allowAbsolutePathsWhenDelegated,defaultPath">
  <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="401.htm" />
  <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="403.htm" />
  <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="404.htm" />
  <error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="405.htm" />
  <error statusCode="406" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="406.htm" />
  <error statusCode="412" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="412.htm" />
  <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="500.htm" />
  <error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="501.htm" />
  <error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="502.htm" />
</httpErrors>
```

with:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

in you IIS config file.

OR

1. List item
2. Stop IIS
3. Open the IIS config file
4. Search for `<section name="httpErrors" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />` and change Deny to Allow.
5. Look for `<httpErrors>` in `<system.webserver>`. If it has `lockAllAttributesExcept="errorMode"`, remove the attribute and value.
6. In command, run `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "<Your Website>/<Your virtual directory>" -section:system.webServer/httpErrors - existingResponse:PassThrough`
7. Start IIS.

Comment: Environment:
The gateway's webserver is Microsoft IIS 7.0

I am not on Microsoft ISS 7.0, I am on a Windowsserver which is hosting a Cognos server.

But thanks searching